# How do I make text "bold" in email body

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have text Fields that populate into the body of an email.
**Question** - How can i make the first and last name show in bold (within the email that is being sent) ?

This is my code for the email

```
    // Send Email ----------------------------
    @IBAction func SendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.setPreferredSendingEmailAddress(EmailFrom.text ?? "")
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients([DefaultEmail.text ?? ""])
            mail.setSubject(DefaultSubject.text ?? "")
            mail.setMessageBody("\(String(describing: DateTextField.text ?? "nil"))</br></br>\n\(String(describing: FirstName.text ?? "nil"))\n\(String(describing: LastName.text ?? "nil"))</br></br>\n\(String(describing: Street.text ?? "nil"))</br>\n\(String(describing: Area.text ?? "nil"))\n\(String(describing: PostCode.text ?? "nil"))</br></br>\nPhone: \(String(describing: Phone.text ?? "nil"))</br>\nEmail: \(String(describing: Email.text ?? "nil"))</br></br>\nReference: \(String(describing: Reference.text ?? "nil"))</br>\nOther Details: \(String(describing: OtherDetailsField.text ?? "nil")) ", isHTML: true)

            present(mail, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("Application is not able to send an email")

        }

        }

//MARK: MFMail Compose ViewController Delegate method
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

        // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Add a `<strong>` tag?

Comment: `<b>\(firstName)</b>`

Comment: neither work, the error they give me is '<' is not a prefix unary operator

Comment: Got it working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `<strong>` or `<b>` tag in your mail content. wrap the text inside the tag, whatever you want to show bold. but you should have `Content-Type: text/html` in your mail header, otherwise, the email will not show up bold text and consider it as plaintext. when you set the content type of email to `text/html` you will be able to use Html tags in mail body and they going to be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

This the code i had

```
mail.setMessageBody("\(String(describing: FirstName.text ?? "nil"))\n\(String(describing: LastName.text ?? "nil"))
```

This the modified code

```
mail.setMessageBody("\<strong>(String(describing: FirstName.text ?? "nil"))\n\(String(describing: LastName.text ?? "nil"))</strong>
```